# select type on a member of a type

Tags: fortran, polymorphism

I am trying to use the `select type` construct on a member of a type:

```
module m_bla
   type t_example
      class(t_poly), allocatable :: poly
   end type

   type, abstract :: t_poly
      integer :: a
   end type

   type, extends(t_poly) :: t_b
      integer :: b
   end type

   type, extends(t_poly) :: t_c
      integer :: c
   end type
end module m_bla

program main 
   use m_bla
   implicit none

   class(t_example), allocatable :: ex

   allocate(t_c::ex%poly)

   ex%poly%a = 12

   select type(ex%poly)
   class is(t_b)
      write (*,*) "b"
   class is(t_c)
      write (*,*) "c"
   end select
end program
```

However, the compilers complains:

```
test.f90(29): error #8253: If selector expression in SELECT TYPE is not a named variable, associate-name=> shall appear.
   select type(ex%poly)
---^
```

I tried to understand what Intel is trying to tell me [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-select-type), but I can't make sense of it. I experimented with `associate-name=>` a little, but I couldn't make it compile. How do I use `associate-name=>` properly, so that I can select the type of `ex%poly`.

Comment: What was your "experiment" with `associate-name=>`?  Something like `select type (poly=>ex%poly)`?

Comment: I tried `poly=>ex` and `associate-name=>poly%ex`. Yours compiles, but crashes `forrtl: severe (408): fort: (7): Attempt to use pointer EX when it is not associated with a target`

Comment: Your runtime complaint about the "pointer" `ex` (ignore ifort's incorrect use of that word) comes from the unrelated fact that you haven't allocated `ex` before trying to allocate the component of `ex`.